# ruby/rails: push & chat server for android

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openfire, faye, juggernaut

- Why another push server?
  Google C2DM does not work well in some regions.
- How to create a push server using ruby/rails?
  Well, it's my real question. I've been googled for a few days.
- Options: IMPP(OpenFire), Juggernaut, Faye, AndroidPn.
  It leads me to confusion. My requirement is simple, light weight push service and light weight text chat. They're just small part of the project.
  Which one is better?

Comment: why people rate down without any comments?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Pusher](http://pusher.com)

Third-party JS-centric push service. I think it works with web socket (which I believe Android does not support), but you'll have to look at its compatibility.

I think this is what you need. I'll leave the details unless you want them!

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of what I need. For now, I'm still search open source solution.